# Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I have created a new react-native project using:

> npx react-native init

But on App.js there is an error here:

```
const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  return (
...
)}
```

There is a red underline in "() => React$Node"

And the error is:

> Type annotations can only be used in TypeScript files

I know that this can be fixed by just using "const App = () => { ", but I remember that I have created some other projects before that would not have this error when created. I noticed that this started to happen only after I created a project with template typescript. Now every project I create start like this, and I don't think this is the only thing on the code that is different, because I'm finding a lot of odd errors that wouldn't happen before. The project now will only render right if I use typescript, even if I change this line.

My question is: How can I go back to when the project would not require typescript to work??

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that your file name is `App.js`.  You need to change is to `App.tsx`.